# Unexpected behaviour with rendering a list of buttons in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to generate a list of buttons using this method. I rewrote it as a test instance and the behaviour is the same - when you render the buttons, the function in onClick is called and cannot be called again by clicking the generated buttons. In this case 1 to 5 are logged.

```
function App() {

const [buttonList, setButtonList] = useState();

const experimental = async (e) => {
  const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
  const listItems = array.map((item) =>
      <li key={item}>
      <button onClick={console.log(item)}>This is a test</button>
      </li>
    );
  setButtonList(listItems);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <button onClick={experimental}>Click to render</button>
        <ul>{buttonList}</ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Could anyone explain this behaviour to me and/or offer a way of doing this which doesn't do this?

Comment: `onClick={()=>console.log(item)}`

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Due to context this. It's must be () => {}. Let's use function and useCallback hook instead.